# Nested views not rendered

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

Very basic example, but doesn't work. What i do wrong?

```
<body ng-app="App"></body>

<div ui-view="navbar"></div>
<div ui-view="sidebar"></div>
<div ui-view="content"></div>

<script>

    var App = angular.module('App', ['ui.router']);

    App.config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/users');

        $stateProvider
            .state('users', {
                url: '/users',
                views: {
                    'navbar':  {template: '<p>Navigation</p>'},
                    'sidebar': {template: '<a href="#users/123">Link</a>'}
                }
            })
            .state('users.item', {
                url: '/:id',
                views: {
                    'content': {template: 'User info'}
                }
            });

    });

</script>
```

When click on link - app become 'users.item' state, but views.content will be not rendered

Comment: can u add a fiddle to show it not working?

Comment: from ui router docs http://plnkr.co/edit/SDOcGS?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to nest the content view in the template:

```
'sidebar': { template: '<a href="#users/123">Link</a><div ui-view="content"></div>' }
```

rather than having it in the body.